# Two list element wise comparison using filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, filter, python-itertools

I have two lists of numbers:

```
l1 = [12, 3, 4, 5, 7]
l2 = [ 6, 8, 4, 2, 4]
```

I want to retrieve all the elements from `l1` that are bigger than the elements from `l2` (element-wise comparison)

So far I only achieved

```
results = list(map(operator.gt,l1,l2)
```

Which returns me a `[True,False,...]` list. But I want the values itself.

I would like to do it without any for loop thanks. I was thinking about `filter()` or `itertools()`

Thanks

Comment: So you want the `max` from each pair?

Comment: Nops. Only those from l1 bigger than l2

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I read it as wanting only values from `l1` *if* they are the max of the pair; `l2` values are never in the result.

Comment: What output are you expecting, then? It seems like you want to map to either `l1`'s value or `None` then filter out the `None`s

Comment: And also would be interesting to have the indices where the condition succedded.

Comment: Maybe `[x for x, y in zip(l1, l2) if x > y]`?

Comment: I did that. But want to know if it is possible with filter or itertools

Comment: To make things clear, please add an example of expected output

Comment: expected result = [12,5,7]

Comment: `list(map(operator.itemgetter(0), filter(lambda x: operator.gt(*x),zip(l1,l2))))`? But that's just a silly way to do this for the sake of avoiding the word `for`. This still has a loop by the way, it's just hidden. (Not possible to do this without a loop)

Comment: `list(filter(None, [a if a > b else None for a, b in zip(lst_1, lst_2)]))`

Comment: If you are okay with using `numpy`, you can convert `l1` and `l2` to numpy arrays and do: `result = l1[l1>l2].tolist()`

Answer (score 2):

you can use a list comprehension:

```
[a for a, b in zip(l1, l2) if a > b]
```

---

or you can use:

```
from operator import gt, itemgetter

list(map(itemgetter(1), filter(itemgetter(0), zip(map(gt, l1, l2), l1))))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but I want to use filter or itertools functions

Comment: @JPV yes I have updated my answer, but the list comprehension looks nicer :)

Comment: that is something I was looking for so I can understand better the operator too. Can you explain the itemgetter function here please?

Comment: the `itemgetter(1)` will grab the elements from position 1 for example if you are doing `itemgetter(1)((1, 2))` will return 2

Comment: so in our example, filter(itemgetter(0), zip(map(gt, l1, l2), l1)) is filtering by the output of map right?

Comment: @JPV yes, will filter after map it is executed (one by one)

Comment: I though you would need a list() before map() though